# splitting field over $Z_3$ (for large degree of polynomial)

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field

Could you verify(or advise) this solving process?

After I solve some typical exercise concerned with splitting field, Galois group,

I made a following problem. But '**large degree**' of f(x) bother me...

$ $

> **The origin exercise.** (I want some advice for my solving process.)
>
> Let $K$ be a splitting field of a polynomial $x^4 -2$ over a field $Z_3$.
>
> Find a order of $K$.

$x^4-2=x^4+1=(x^2-x-1)(x^2+x-1)$

and $x^2-x-1$ and $x^2+x-1$ are irreducible.

GF($3^2$)=
$\{$roots of $x^{{3}^2}-x$$\}$

And $(x^2-x-1)(x^2+x-1)$ divides $x^{{3}^2}-x$

Therefore $K$=GF($3^2$). Hence $|K|=3^2$.

$$
$$

> **(And I made a problem like this)**
>
> Let $K$ be a splitting field of a polynomial $x^8+1$ over a field $Z_3$
>
> What is order of $K$ (i.e. $|K|$)

I used [Germain identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain), so I get

$x^8+1=x^8+4=(x^4-2x^2+2)(x^4+2x^2+2)$

and $x^4-2x^2+2$ and $x^4+2x^2+2$ are irreducible.

GF($3^4$)=$\{$ roots of $x^{3^4} -x$ $\}$

And $(x^4-2x^2+2)(x^4+2x^2+2)$ divides $x^{3^4} -x$

Therefore $K$=GF($3^4$), $|K|=3^4$

$$$$

> **Question1.**
>
> Is my process right?
>
> Could you give me some advice, please?
>
> (Actually I think ... I have a superficial knowledge about splitting field)

$$
$$

> **$\color{red}{Question2.}$**
>
> In the second problem (I made), degree 8 is large for me.
>
> If I didn't come up with Germain identity,,,,
>
> How can I solve this problem??
>
> Id est, I'd like to know '$\color{red}{the}$ $\color{red}{general}$ $\color{red}{method}$' of solving these type (large degree).

$$
$$

Thanks in advance.

And I apologize if a sentence cannot be smooth.